# SharePoint REST OData Query - Title has curly braces, how to retrieve

Tags: rest, sharepoint, odata

I have a simple list, which has a title field.  There are certain values in that Title field that have curly brackets.  For example 'Client {Formerly known as Something else}'

I am trying to retrieve this record using OData.  Here is my query:

https://xxx.sharepoint.com/forms/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('clients')/items?$select=ID,Title&$filter=Title%20eq%20%27Client%20%7BFormally%20known%20as%20Something%20else%7D%27

I also tried

https://xxx.sharepoint.com/forms/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('clients')/items?$select=ID,Title&$filter=Title%20eq%20%27Client%20{Formally%20known%20as%20Something%20else}%27

I do not get any records returned.  When I enter a simple value in the filter, it works fine.  So how do I escape or handle curly braces?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, it may be URL encoding problem. You can double check your URL string.
According to your description, I have tried to use {} on the API endpoint provided by graph which is fine without encoding issue.

Below is the url I requested:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(givenName,'{1222}')
```

This is my response data

```
    {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "f4d2e619-43b9-40f1-b926-78696ccf976e",
            "businessPhones": [],
            "displayName": "{1222}",
            "givenName": "{1222}",
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": "",
            "mobilePhone": null,
            "officeLocation": null,
            "preferredLanguage": null,
            "surname": null,
            "userPrincipalName": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried using curly braces in the URL - still no luck.  I tried using the startswith method, and that also didn't work.Have you tried this with the SharePoint REST API, not the Graph?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode those special characters as Unicode and escape with a % symbol. See below.

To retrieve an item with a Title field value of: Client {Text in Curlys}
API call: /_api/lists/getbytitle('Sample')/items?$filter=Title eq 'Client %u007BText in Curlys%u007D'

[Here’s a related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480388/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-odata-filter-ignores-unicode-characters-such-as-german)

Hope that helps!